# Keycloak continuously redirects to login page

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have setup the keycloak but it continuously redirects to login page in a loop.
I got the below error in logs:

2022-02-22 12:41:42,003 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-2) type=REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=10.x.x.x, error=invalid_token, grant_type=refresh_token, client_auth_method=client-secret

Can anyone guide?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind apache/nginx, perhaps set httpOnly cookie! This can be reason that behavior in keycloak 15.0.2